# How to inherit aws credentials from terraform in local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I have a resource in terraform that I need to run an AWS command on after it is created. But I want it to run using the same AWS credentials that terraform is using. The AWS provider is using a profile which it then uses to assume a role:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "terraform"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = local.my_arn
  }
}
```

I had hoped that terraform would expose the necessary environment variables, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use role assumption via the AWS configuration? Doc: [Using an IAM Role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

**~/.aws/config:**

```
[user1]
aws_access_key_id =  ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY

[test-assume]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-assume
source_profile = user1
```

**main.tf:**

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = var.aws_profile
  version = "~> 2.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

variable "aws_profile" {
  default = "test-assume"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
  ami           = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "subnet-002df68a36948517c"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws sts get-caller-identity --profile ${var.aws_profile}"
  }
}
```

---

If you can't, here's a really messy way of doing it. I don't particularly recommend this method, but it will work. This has a dependency on `jq` but you could also use something else to parse the output from the `aws sts assume-role` command

**main.tf:**

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = var.aws_profile
  version = "~> 2.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.assume_role
  }
}

variable "aws_profile" {
  default = "default"
}

variable "assume_role" {
  default = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-assume"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
  ami           = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "subnet-002df68a36948517c"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${var.assume_role} --role-session-name Testing --profile ${var.aws_profile} --output json > test.json && export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' test.json` && export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' test.json` && export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken' test.json` && aws sts get-caller-identity && rm test.json && unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID && unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY && unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Creating AWS configuration might be possible, but I'd really like to avoid it, because 1. I have a lot of roles that would need to configured like this 2. Multiple users would need to have these profiles configured, and automating that configuration without overwriting existing config would be tricky.